# Hadoop Cassandra job not reading all input rows

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have a quite simple Hadoop job using Cassandra as input and output. Here is the job configuration code (nothing special):

```
Job job = new Job(getConf(), JOB_NAME);
job.setJarByClass(getClass());

job.setMapperClass(CassandraHadoopCounterMapper.class);
job.setReducerClass(CassandraHadoopCounterReducer.class);
job.setCombinerClass(CassandraHadoopCounterCombiner.class);

job.setInputFormatClass(CqlInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(CqlOutputFormat.class);

job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

job.setOutputKeyClass(Map.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(List.class);

ConfigHelper.setInputColumnFamily(job.getConfiguration(), KEYSPACE, INPUT_COLUMN_FAMILY, WIDE_ROWS);
ConfigHelper.setOutputColumnFamily(job.getConfiguration(), KEYSPACE, OUTPUT_COLUMN_FAMILY);

ConfigHelper.setInputRpcPort(job.getConfiguration(), "9160");
ConfigHelper.setOutputRpcPort(job.getConfiguration(), "9160");

ConfigHelper.setInputInitialAddress(job.getConfiguration(), "localhost");
ConfigHelper.setOutputInitialAddress(job.getConfiguration(), "localhost"); 

ConfigHelper.setInputPartitioner(job.getConfiguration(), Murmur3Partitioner.class.getName());
ConfigHelper.setOutputPartitioner(job.getConfiguration(), Murmur3Partitioner.class.getName());

String query = "UPDATE " + KEYSPACE + "." + OUTPUT_COLUMN_FAMILY + " SET c = ?";
CqlConfigHelper.setOutputCql(job.getConfiguration(), query);

//aditional properties:
CqlConfigHelper.setInputCQLPageRowSize(job.getConfiguration(), "2000");
ConfigHelper.setInputSplitSize(job.getConfiguration(), 4 * 64 * 1024);
```

My input cassandra table have 10k rows.
In hadoop I have set `max mappers = 2` and `max reducers = 2`
In job counters i can see the following:

```
Map input records=4000
```

Which is `InputCQLPageRowSize * mappers`
If `InputCQLPageRowSize` is not set then `Map input records` equals 2000 (because default `InputCQLPageRowSize` is 1000)

My questions:
**How to make my hadoop job to read all rows in input table?**

The job is run entirely locally on my PC.
I am using Cassandra v2.0.11 and Hadoop v1.0.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was related to a bug in cassandra 2.0.11 that added a strange LIMIT clause in underlying CQL query run to read data to the map task:

I posted that issue to cassandra jira:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9074

It turned out that that problem was stricly related to the following bug fixed in cassandra 2.0.12:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8166